# Average acoustics power of sound

Tags: acoustics, intensity

We know that acoustics power of sound is equal to intensity of sound times area of the sphere centered with sound source, but my question is what is average acoustic power and if there is any difference between average acoustic power and acoustic power of sound?

Answer (score 2):

> We know that acoustics power of sound is equal to intensity of sound times area of the sphere centered with sound source,

That's only true for an omnidirectional source. Otherwise you need to integrate the intensity over (any) closed surface.

> but my question is what is average acoustic power and if there is any difference between average acoustic power and acoustic power of sound?

That depends somewhat on how exactly you define the terms. For a sound wave in air, I would say "no". Can you provide a reference that defines "acoustic power" and "sound power" differently ?